# Why is my function not returning null pointer?

Tags: c, parsing, pointers, stm32, strtok

I have a problem with visual code, everything works fine on the online compiler, but while trying it on stm32 nucleo it doesn't return `NULL`, where is the problem? It cannot break the `while` loop.

```
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h> 
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <ctype.h>

int funk(char *skai) {
    char delim[] = "+-=";
    int i = 0;
    float x, d = 0;
    char *array[2];
    char *ptr = strtok(skai, delim);
    while (ptr != NULL) {
        array[i++] = ptr;
        ptr = strtok(NULL, delim); // <---- doesnt return null, endless loop
    }
    int a = atoi(array[0]);
    float b = atof(array[1]);
    int c = atoi(array[2]);
    if (c != 0) {
        d = b * b - 4 * a * c;
        if (d > 0) {
            float root1 = (-b + sqrt(d)) / (2 * a);
            float root2 = (-b - sqrt(d)) / (2 * a);
            if (root1 > root2) {
                x = root1;
            } else {
                x = root2;
            }
        } else {
            x = -b / (2 * a);
        }
    } else {
        x = b / a;
    } //printf("%0.3f\n", x);
    return x;
}

int main(void) {
    char rxd[20] = "2x^2+x/5+2=0";
    funk(rxd);
}
```

Comment: Provide a [mre].

Comment: It shouldn't return NULL after 2 times but after 3, "2x", "2", "0"

Comment: When I run the code currently in the question (using Apple Clang 11.0.0 with `-O3` on macOS 10.14.6), it aborts. When I change `char *array[2];` to `char array[20];`, it runs and completes with no output. Inserting `printf("i = %d.\n", i);` into the `strtok` loop shows `strtok` returns four non-null pointers followed by a null pointer, as expected.

Comment: @EricPostpischil I had a little laugh reading this [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60756974/why-is-my-function-not-returning-null-pointer/60758019#comment107496343_60756974) trying to find out why your good [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60757163/2410359) did not solve OP's trouble as we both independently change `[2]` to `[20]`.  Finally traced down to OP's moving target equation.

Comment: The only problem I see with your `while` loop is the array-bounds overrun that others have already remarked upon.  Your array needs at least four elements to accommodate the (up to) three addends and the result of a quadratic equation expressed in the form presented.  Are you sure the failure is there?  Bugs in the code for extracting coefficients appear likely to lead to an attempt to compute the square root of a negative number for the input presented (and that is an issue you would need to catch even if you extracted the coefficients correctly).

Comment: srttok as most functions requiring dynamic allocation is not a good idea in the uC world. Better write your own function instead

Comment: @P__J__: `strtok` does not require dynamic allocation.

Answer (score 3):

Given `skai` pointing to an array of `char` containing “2x+2=0”, a sequence of calls to `strtok` with delimiters “+-=” is expected to return first a pointer to (the first character of) “2x”, then “2”, then “0”, then a null pointer. The code as written attempts to store these values in `array[0]`, `array[1]`, and `array[2]`. However, `array` has no element 2 since it was defined with only two elements. So the program overflows the array, and the resulting behavior of the program is not defined by the C standard. It may be the program is then overwriting memory in such a way as to cause `strtok` to misbehave.

Change the definition of `array` to be larger, and, inside the loop calling `strtok`, monitor the value of `i`: If it reaches the limit of the array size, print an error message and terminate the function (or the entire program).

Comment: thank you, yes, i changed it, but it still does not solve the problem, it never return null and cant break while loop

Comment: @KarolRawdo: You need to provide a [mre]. The code currently in the question does not compile: The `#include` statements are missing and `d` and `x` are not defined.

Answer (score 2):

Your program has multiple problems:

- you should try not to modify the argument string: `strtok()` modifies the string pointed to by its first argument, which is a nasty side effect and in your case loses important information such as the sign of the next constant.
- you do not handle `/`
- `array` has just 2 entries, causing undefined behavior for most equations that have more terms.

Here is a modified version that uses `strtod()` and manual parsing:

```
#include <math.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int funk(const char *exp, double *x1, double *x2) {
    double coef[3] = { 0, 0, 0 };
    double d, e, a, b, c, sign, part;
    int n;
    const char *p = exp;
    char *q;

    part = 1;
    for (;;) {
        p += strspn(p, " \t\r\n"); // skip whitespace
        if (!*p)
            break;
        if (*p == '=') {
            p++;
            if (part < 0)
                return -1;
            part = -1;
            continue;
        }
        d = 1;
        sign = part;
        if (*p == '+') {
            p++;
        } else
        if (*p == '-') {
            sign = -1;
            p++;
        }
        if (*p != 'x') {
            d = strtod(p, &q);
            if (p == q)
                return -1;
            p = q;
        }
        d *= sign;
        n = 0;
        if (*p == '/') {
            p++;
            e = strtod(p, &q);
            if (p == q)
                return -1;
            p = q;
            d /= e;
        }
        if (*p == 'x') {
            p++;
            n = 1;
            if (*p == '^') {
                p++;
                n = strtol(p, &q, 10);
                if (p == q)
                    return -1;
                p = q;
                if (n < 0 || n > 2)
                    return -1;
            }
        }
        if (*p == '/') {
            p++;
            e = strtod(p, &q);
            if (p == q)
                return -1;
            p = q;
            d /= e;
        }
        coef[n] += d;
    }
    a = coef[2];
    b = coef[1];
    c = coef[0];
    d = b * b - 4 * a * c;
    if (a > 0 || a < 0) {
        /* quadratic equation */
        if (d < 0) {
            return -2;
        } else
        if (d > 0) {
            *x1 = (-b + sqrt(d)) / (2 * a);
            *x2 = (-b - sqrt(d)) / (2 * a);
            return 2;
        } else {
            *x1 = -b / (2 * a);
            return 1;
        }
    }
    if (b < 0 || b > 0) {
        /* first order equation */
        *x1 = 0 + -c / b;
        return 1;
    }
    /* constant equation */
    if (c > 0 || c < 0) {
        return 0;
    } else {
        return 3;
    }
}

void solve(const char *exp) {
    double x1, x2;
    switch (funk(exp, &x1, &x2)) {
    case 0:
        printf("%s -> no solution\n", exp);
        break;
    case 1:
        printf("%s -> single root x=%g\n", exp, x1);
        break;
    case 2:
        printf("%s -> two roots x1=%g, x2=%g\n", exp, x1, x2);
        break;
    case -2:
        printf("%s -> two imaginary roots\n", exp);
        break;
    case 3:
        printf("%s -> true for all x\n", exp);
        break;
    default:
        printf("not a quadratic equation: %s\n", exp);
        break;
    }
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    if (argc > 1) {
        for (int i = 1; i < argc; i++)
            solve(argv[i]);
    } else {
        solve("2x^2+x/5+2=0");
        solve("x^2+2x+1=0");
        solve("x^2=49");
        solve("x=49");
        solve("x=0");
        solve("2=2");
        solve("1=0");
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Array too small - by two.<sup>*1</sup>

I made `array[]` much larger and added `printf("%d '%s'\n", i, ptr)`

```
char *array[20];
char *ptr = strtok(skai, delim);
while (ptr != NULL) {
  printf("%d '%s'\n", i, ptr);
  array[i++] = ptr;
  ptr = strtok(NULL, delim); // <---- doesnt return null, endless loop
}
```

The output was

```
0 '2x^2'
1 'x/5'
2 '2'
3 '0'
```

So apparently `array[]` needed to be at least `array[4]`.

Recommend to add protection when parsing or use a different approach.

```
if (i+1 >= sizeof array/sizeof array[0]) {
  // Handle/report error somehow
}
array[i++] = ptr;
```

---

Aside: If using `float` variables, might as well use `float` functions.

```
// float root1 = (-b + sqrt(d)) / (2 * a);
// ---------------------v
float root1 = (-b + sqrtf(d)) / (2 * a);
```

---

<sup>*1</sup>

Post had changed from `"2x+2=0"` to `"2x^2+x/5+2=0"`

Comment: `may have some unknown requirements for float` - most stm32 has SP float FPU. It is this "secret" requirement.

Comment: @P__J__ Thanks for the tip.

Comment: BTW - `strtok` & uC == bad design. Instantly shows that the programmer has a very limited uC experience. Many standards even ban completely malloc & friends.

Comment: The `strtok()` approach is bound to fail: `x^2-1=0` will be parsed as `x2+1=0`  :)